# Runtime error : this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key saveButtonInProfile

Tags: objective-c

By mistake I gave a property to a UIButton and named it *saveButtonProfile instead of an action to the save button. Once I delete the property for the button, I get a runtime error "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key saveButtonInProfile."
How to dereference the property for a button so that I can get rid of this error? 
Using Xcode 4.5 with iOS 6.0 simulator with ARC enabled.

Comment: Text editor knows nothing about what a string "saveButtonProfile" means, so there is no reason for it to crash when you delete one. If you are not editing objective-c in plain text editor, it is not objective-c question, but question about that particular tool you use to generate it. So the question should have been tagged differently. Probably `xcode`. And of course, questions about specific problems belong on stack overflow if they are about programming or on superuser if they are about using an application (this one being somewhere in between).

Comment: ... or I dind't understand what you are even talking about in which case the question really needs more context (it still does not belong here in any case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created the property it created two things. The property and the connection to it.

You have now deleted the property but haven't yet deleted the connection.

In IB right click on the button and press the X next to the connected outlet.